# heroku keys:add error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner in Rails and I've followed ruby.railstutorials.org until I stuck with this section http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:1.4.1

after I installed heroku gem by `gem install heruku`

I typed `heroku keys:add` then I got these errors.

```
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:161:in `start'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
abcs-MacBook-Pro-2:first_app xxx$
```

Could you please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the gem again with the right spelling:

```
gem install heroku
```

Check the version of the ruby you are using with

```
rvm list
ruby -v
gem list
```

You need to switch to the right ruby with

```
rvm use <ruby version>
```

And then install heroku again.

Comment: Sorry for my mistyping on the post above.
I've already install heroku by `gem install heroku` with/without sudo but the error show above.

Comment: Thanks Anil
It was fixed.

after I typed `gem list`
then I changed  `gem 'sqlite3', ' 1.3.5'`
in gemfile to `gem 'sqlite3', '>= 1.3.5'` and also for jquery-rails

Answer (score 0):

Get [Home Brew](https://brew.sh/) then run the command "brew doctor". If it tells you that you have errors, fix those errors.

I'm guessing you are on a Mac and that you might be running MacPorts. There are problems with this because MacPorts uses older libs that rvm tries to access. You need to remove opt and a bunch of stuff from your paths where brew doctor complans.